# QI Application of JPOS

Tags: java, jpos

We were using QI (Along with JPOS+JCARD)Application with jPOS 1.9.8 baae23b and Vaadin 6.7.3
we have customized the application for adding few rules for transactions. 
Now Customer needs a dashboard component in QI Application for the customized rules parts we have added.

Is there any internal support for the Graphs, Pie Charts in the QI Application or do we need to integrate a new component for this to work. Also we have seen few options like vaadin charts https://vaadin.com/add-ons/charts which is licensed product. Correct me if my understanding is wrong.Need help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for find the better and effective way for creating graphs was answered by the vaadin site itself.

There is a Addon for vaadin i.e, **JFreeChart wrapper for Vaadin** (https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/jfreechart-wrapper-for-vaadin:vaadin)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new Vaadin widgetset with the add on components you want to use.

Comment: yes we tried with vaadin-charts and we are not sure we can get it with jpos license as well or can it be integrated with the application.

Comment: I don't think this is a technical question suitable for Stack Exchange. You need to check that with your legal team.